# XAML ControlTemplate makes buttons unclickable on android devices. Any ideas on how to make them clickable again?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I have a page that requires the user to choose between two options- I'm using a radio button for it, but for the formatting I needed to make a custom ControlTemplate so the button can look like all our others, where instead of a little bubble to fill in the button, it is a large, clickable button that changes background color & text color when clicked on. The custom template I'm using is as follows:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="FrameRadioTemplate">
            <Frame Padding="0" BorderColor="#006A97" CornerRadius="1"       
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="80" HorizontalOptions="Start">

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#008000"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ffffff"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid WidthRequest="70">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

And when viewing this in Visual Studio's Windows Machine, it works fine- I can click on my radio buttons, they select, everything works fine. But when I tried it on Android, suddenly the radio buttons are unclickable- they display & show up how I want, but nothing happens when I tap on them.

After some testing, I can see that using a standard radiobutton in my android app is functional, and clickable- but after adding this template & referencing it within the button, suddenly it can't be clicked on. Within the button itself, I am setting it up with this code:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" 
             RadioButtonGroup.SelectedValue="{Binding ShiftSelection}">
    <RadioButton x:Name="Option1" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FrameRadioTemplate}"
                 Value="Option1">
        <RadioButton.Content>
            <Label Text="Option1" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>
    <RadioButton x:Name="Option2" ControlTemplate="{StaticResource FrameRadioTemplate}"
                 Value="Option2">
        <RadioButton.Content>
            <Label Text="Option2" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </RadioButton.Content>
    </RadioButton>
</StackLayout>
```

I have also tried making a custom control to override the radiobutton to be a large, clickable button like how I want it, but that also is new territory for me so I'm not sure how to get that to work either.